# Should I use try-with-resources on ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

Using `ComboPooledDataSource` as a db connection pool. It seems like connections are being opened to frequently against my database. All of the queries use a `try-with-resources` block when opening the connection. My hypothesis is that using the `try-with-resources` block when opening the connection is also auto closing it, so the connection with my DB never gets re-used.  Code in question looks like:

```
try (Connection conn = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection()) {
    // ... do stuff with conn
}
```

I'm thinking that instead of using the try with resources it should just be a regular try statement and should not close the connection... leave that up to the `ComboPooledDataSource`. It would look like:

```
try {
    Connection conn = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection()
    // ... do stuff with conn but don't close it
}
```

Comment: Closing a connection obtained from a pool is what allows it to be reused.  So, you were correct to put the Connection in a try-with-resources statement.